# SSRS: Parameter population from a dataset

Tags: reporting-services

I have a dataset with start dates, end dates, and term codes.  The user will enter in an academic year.  The academic year will be used to determine the three term codes for that year.  I want to use those three codes to select start and end dates for each term, which will go into the main query.  I can achieve this by setting up three datasets that will hold the term code, start date, and end date for each term and populating the start and end date parameters from there, but what I want to know is if there is a more dynamic way to achieve this.

Thanks!

Some clarification.  I want a way to populate all six parameters from one dataset, not each start and end date getting its own dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure of how your data is set up, so I'm going to make a few guesses here. You can return six separate dates by pivoting the Start and End Dates for each Term:

```
declare @TermCodes table(AcademicYear int,TermCode varchar(50))
insert into @TermCodes
    values
        (2014,'FL14'),
        (2014,'SP14'),
        (2014,'SM14')

declare @TermDates table(TermCode varchar(50), StartDate date,EndDate date)
insert into @TermDates
    values
        ('FL14','20140915','20141215'),
        ('SP14','20150115','20150415'),
        ('SM14','20150515','20150815')

declare @AcademicYear int
set @AcademicYear = 2014

select
    min(StartDate1) StartDate1,
    min(EndDate1) EndDate1,
    min(StartDate2) StartDate2,
    min(EndDate2) EndDate2,
    min(StartDate3) StartDate3,
    min(EndDate3) EndDate3
from    (
        select
            td.StartDate,
            td.EndDate,
            'StartDate' + cast(row_number() over(order by td.StartDate) as char(1)) StartDates,
            'EndDate' + cast(row_number() over(order by td.StartDate) as char(1)) EndDates
        from @TermCodes tc
            inner join @TermDates td
                on td.TermCode = tc.TermCode
        where tc.AcademicYear = @AcademicYear
        ) t
    pivot   (
            max(StartDate)
            for StartDates in(StartDate1,StartDate2,StartDate3)
            ) sd
    pivot   (
            max(EndDate)
            for EndDates in(EndDate1,EndDate2,EndDate3)
            ) ed
```

Comment: How do I get those into SSRS parameters?

Comment: I'm not sure how much you know about SSRS, so forgive me if I over instruct.

1. Right Click your first Parameter (StartDate1 in this example) and select Parameter Properties
2. Click Default Values
3. Click "Get values from a Query"
4. Select your Dataset that returns each Date
5. Select the StartDate1 Value to set as a default.
6. Repeat for Each parameter.

Comment: Had to a little tweaking as the term codes and dates were all in one table, but it seems to work.  Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome again! :) If my response answers your question, please consider marking it as the answer and voting it up. Thanks!